# Postgresql update from 9.6 on 11 on debian10

Tags: debian, postgresql

I want to migrate from Potgresql 9.6 to 11 on debian10. But I get this error while wanting to install Postgresql 11:

```
apt-get install postgresql-11

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-11 : Depends: postgresql-client-11 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: postgresql-common (>= 194~) but 181+deb9u3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The output of the command **apt-cache policy** is:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now

 500 http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/4.0/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Zabbix,n=stretch,l=zabbix,c=main,b=amd64
     origin repo.zabbix.com

 500 http://repo.squashtest.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9.0,o=Squashtest.org,a=stable unstable,n=stretch,l=Squashtest.org,c=main,b=amd64
     origin repo.squashtest.org

 500 http://security.debian.org buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=10,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org

 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=buster-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.debian.org

 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=10.7,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin ftp.debian.org

 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     release v=10.7,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using these two commands:

sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo aptitude install postgresql-11